# Exception finding control in nested page (asp.net)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, code-behind

I was developing something for my webpage that was working but now is not.

I want to load a control (ul) in my aspx.cs page, but it is throwing an exception.

my html is like this:

```
<ul class="offer-list offer-small list-content" id="latestOffers" runat="server">
                <li>
```

my codebehind:

```
 ullo = HtmlGenericControl) this.Master.FindControl("ContentPage").FindControl("latestOffers");
```

This is in my page load method.

I'm getting something like this:

```
base {System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl} 
= {InnerText = '((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl)
(((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)(ulLatestOffers)))).InnerText
' threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException'}
```

This was working, but not anymore.

What is wrong? Could you guys help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
ullo = HtmlGenericControl) this.Master.FindControl("ContentPage").FindControl("latestOffers");
```

I'm guessing this line is located at your constructor. Add a new method, lets say `InitControl()` and run this code there.

Comment: I've already did that. Didnt work. I created a method and called it from the page load method.